# Binding WPF textBox Large Text async with possibility of cancellation

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

I have listbox and for each selected item I need bind data (Large Text) to separate TextBox placed on form.

It works fine with small text less than 16 kb.

but with large text I have UI Freeze because of TexBox Rendering is taking long time.

IDEA is to have Async Binding (even Manually on selected even Line by Line), with ability to have cancelation of binding. Cancellation should occur if new item will selected during a rendering.

P.S. Same code in WinForm works much faster.

Could you help me on that, or give another idea ?

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: Show your code so that we can see what the issue might be and how to help you.

Comment: We're not here to write code for you. [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Read about UI virtualization here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/optimizing-performance-controls

Answer (score 0):

I found way to achieve result.
1) Using FlowDocumentReader instead of TextBox
2) Load document large text with async, and cancels previous load, if new document load occurs.

Just want to share with a solution to the others.